# How to get the new values after using makehgtform?

Tags: matlab

Hi all so I have the following MATLAB code. [x,y,z] are point that are defined a few lines above thisn on my script (but too long to include on here). [x,y,z] are coordinates of a 3D figure that I plot using plot3. I have rotated the figure by theta_Pos_x and theta_Pos_y and it does it how I want it. However, I would like to extract these new values as I need to do further analysis with these points. Any help is truly appreciated.

```
figure(1)
%Create Transform

t = hgtransform;
plot3(x,y,z,'Parent',t)
Rx = makehgtform('xrotate',theta_Pos_x);
Ry = makehgtform('yrotate',theta_Pos_y);

t.Matrix = Rx;
t.Matrix = Ry;
```

Comment: what is Rx? you defined Ry only

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that. Post has been updated